# Number of subsets that contain only odd numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, intuition

> **Question:** Let $X=\{1, 2, ..., n\}$. where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $n$ be odd. How many subsets of $X$ contain all the odd numbers from $X$?
>
> **Answer:** Since $n$ is odd, $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k\ge0$, so there are $k$ even numbers and $k+1$ odd numbers in $X$. Thus, there are $2^k=2^{(n-1)/2}$ subsets of $X$ containing all the odd numbers in $X$.

I'm very confused by the answer.

If there are $k+1$ odd numbers in $X$, why are there then $2^k=2^{(n-1)/2}$ subsets that only contain odd numbers?

From my understanding, we want to have all subsets of $X=\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ that contain only odd numbers. I thought, when $n$ is odd, there are $(n-1)/2$ even numbers and $(n+1)/2$ odd numbers in the set.

But the answer gives a different value. Or do I misunderstand the wording here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking about subsets that contain all the odd numbers, that does not necessarily mean ONLY odd numbers. E.g., if $n=5$, then $\{1, 2, 3, 5\}$ contains all odd numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm not a native speaker and somehow got confused by the wording. So subsets that contain all odd numbers can also contain $0$ or more even numbers.